# cakephp How to Deleting data of two tables

Tags: cakephp

M new in cakephp.
M using cakephp 2X.
I have model Student and Document.

```
Student hasMany Document

Document belognsTo Student
```

I need to delete documents when i am delete student.
That student's all documents also been delete.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try This :

**In Model :**

```
// In your Student Model
var $hasMany=array('Student'=>array('className'=>'Student',
                                 'foreignKey'=>'student_id',
                                 'dependent'=>true, // true without single quote
                                 'exclusive'=>true
                                )
                );

//In your Document Model
var $belongsTo = array('User'=>array('className'=>'Student',
                                     'foreignKey'=>'student_id'
                             )
                );
```

**In Controller :**

```
$this->Model->delete($item_to_delete_id,true);
```

[Ref link](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/deleting-data.html)